# Running Python in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I need to write my python commands in command line and get the outputs like

```
python -c a = 10
python -c print("Hello {}".format(a))
python -c import math
```

Comment: why would you need that

Comment: for example if you cannot write your code to a file, e.g. if you want to run code on a remote machine you have no write permission to?

Comment: @helvete don't think it will work with the quoting you seem to indicate...

Comment: @norok2: you are right, I misplaced the ending quote - i meant: `python -c "a = 10; <another command>..."`. Deleted the misguiding comment. Thanks for letting me know..

Comment: I need to read some code from a file and give them to python and get answer like:   answerMe(open("a.txt").read()) and I wrote "a=0;a==0" in a.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to your problem would be to write out a `.py` file and run that.

However, I can imagine that for scripting purposes you may need something like this if you cannot write a file. In that case you could separate your commands by `;`, but you are going to be limited to programs without blocks, e.g.:

```
python3 -c "import math; a = 10; print('Hello {} {}'.format(a, math.sin(a)))"

# prints:
# Hello 10 -0.5440211108893698
```

but:

```
python3 -c "import math; a = 10; for i in range(a): print('Hello {} {}'.format(i, math.sin(i)))"
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

but again:

```
python3 -c "import math; a = 10; [print('Hello {} {}'.format(i, math.sin(i))) for i in range(a)]"

# prints:
# Hello 0 0.0
# Hello 1 0.8414709848078965
# Hello 2 0.9092974268256817
# Hello 3 0.1411200080598672
# Hello 4 -0.7568024953079282
# Hello 5 -0.9589242746631385
# Hello 6 -0.27941549819892586
# Hello 7 0.6569865987187891
# Hello 8 0.9893582466233818
# Hello 9 0.4121184852417566
```

the last one is of course bad practice and all (a side-effect in a comprehension, etc.) but kind of works.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a py file and then invoked it from command line.

Inside the name_file.py put:

```
a = 10
print("Hello {}".format(a))
import math
```

In console excute

```
python name_file.py
```

See [python file](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need run a few commands. You can run [Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) with writing `python` inside your command line. There will be `>>>` as a mark that all commands you write will be interpreted by interpreter.

[image: Python interpreter]

Then you can write the commands. After each command you should press ENTER.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> print("Hello {}".format(a))
>>> import math
```

Answer (score 0):

FIRST you have to add the python to your system path
1.right click on THIS PC

2.click on advanced system settings

3. click on environment variables
4. click on the path to edit
5. click on edit

6.search python in START MENU

7.right click on the downloaded package and click on copy full path or if your'e using python 3.6 
you can reinstall and check the path from the install menu

8.add the path to the list

NOW YOU CAN DO THIS
TYPE python in the command prompt and voila 
you should be able to run on the command prompt